# How can I load graphql raw schema from remote server

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo client in nodejs in the client side to communicate server via graphql. Is there a way for the client to download the graphql schema into a string variable?

I know I can send a `query IntrospectionQuery` to get the schema but the format is in json not the gql format. I'd like to download below format:

```
type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
    date: AWSDateTime
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]
    _service: _Service
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Apollo Client does not use your schema in any way. Usually you only need that in development, and then you would use a command line tool to download it.